# how can i sumrows accept a specific values

Tags: r, sum, addition

If I have these data (dat1)

```
`  L1  L2 L3 L4 L5 L6
   1   0   1  0  4  0  
   4   1   0  1  1  0
   1   0   0  1  4  1
```

All the values in the matrix are 0,1,4
I need to sum every row ignoring number 4.
The result like this

```
2
3
3
```

I have more than 900 rows..
I tried these but there is something missing

```
rowSums(subset(dat1,L1!=4)
rowSums(which[dat1!=4])
n4=dat1[dat1==4]<-0
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: i try rowSums(subset(dat.missing,L1!=4)

Comment: rowSums(which[dat.missing!=4])

Comment: Consider adding tags for the programming language you are using.  Also provide more code context for what you have so far.

Comment: I use this command and it works but naybe there is something more profisional : dat1[dat1==4]<-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
dat1[dat1==4] <- 0
rowSums(dat1)
```

If modifying the object is not acceptable just copy it first:

```
dat1Zero <- dat1
dat1[dat1Zero==4] <- 0
rowSums(dat1Zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the values are in (0,1,4) then you just want to count the 1's, no??

```
apply(df,1,function(x)sum(x==1))
# [1] 2 3 3
```